# How can I tell how much memory a specific ColdFusion variable, or each property of a ColdFusion scope is being used?

Tags: caching, variables, memory, coldfusion, memory-management

I'm currently caching a query in ColdFusion. It has a few thousand records and about 30 columns - most of them are VARCHAR columns. I'm curious how much memory this is using, to determine if it's really worth storing it in the cache. How can I find out the amount of memory that is being used by a cached query and/or any variable, really (APPLICATION scope for example)?

Comment: If any of the answers below were correct, make sure you accept one.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CF Enterprise (or Developer), you can open the Server Monitor from the CF Administrator and [view the memory usage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=servermonitor_08.html). Don't do this in a production system though, as the memory tracker can seriously bog down a CF server.

Comment: You can also do it with the ColdFusion development version

Comment: I wonder if FusionReactor would also work -- I'm not currently a user, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: I have an installation of FusionReactor running, and it doesn't currently break down the memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no CF/Java sizeOf() which one might expect to find to do this sort of thing, which is what one might initially expect to be able to do.  Google "java sizeof" for more information than you're likely to want to read on the subject.

As Dan said, there's the server monitor, which will do it.  It also has an API if you want to look at this sort of thing progammatically: http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/adminapi/servermonitoring.cfc.

Docs are here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf363cdd-7ff4.html

Sample code:

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="cfartgallery">
    SELECT  *
    FROM    artists
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#q#">

<cfset oAdmin = createObject("component", "cfide.adminapi.administrator")>
<cfset oAdmin.login("pwd", "adminapi")>

<cfset oMonitor = createObject("component", "cfide.adminapi.servermonitoring")>
<cfset aMetrics = oMonitor.getQueryDetails()>
<cfdump var="#aMetrics#">
```

You need to have server monitoring switched on for this to return anything (cheers to Ray Camden for helping me with that bit ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In [Railo](http://getrailo.org) there is a `SizeOf(obj)` function, which can tell you how much memory is being used by an object.

Depending on how easy it would be to setup, you could consider running your app on Railo, caching the query, then calling `SizeOf` to get the information you want.

It's probably not going to be exactly the same (depends on specifics of how things are stored internally), but should give a rough idea.

*(p.s. Just suggesting to use Railo for this measurement - not suggesting you switch over entirely; unless of course you want to.)*